# multi dimensional array assigning

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
class//
  public:
      double a[3][2][2];

  void f(double b[3][2][2]){

     //How do i assign b to a?
  }
```

How do i assign the arrays.I am stuck with pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A memcpy will do the trick:

```
memcpy(a, b, sizeof(a));
```

Careful not to use `sizeof(b)`, since b is actually a pointer, not an array, so only 4 or 8 bytes will be copied.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the = operator, but it will have to do an element-by-element copy of one array to the other.

Comment: Correct. I also recommend using double*** b instead, to avoid copies.

Comment: Do you mean overload `operator=` for his class?  Or for a 3-dimensional array of doubles?  You cannot implement the latter.

Comment: @revani: A parameter of type `double***` would not accept an argument of type `double[3][2][2]`.

Comment: Yeah, but you can cast it with no problem, which I do not recommend but is perfectly OK.